# Can't compare MongoDB data with javascript array

Tags: arrays, node.js, mongodb

I want to compare the data which I got from Mongo to javascript array. I am using lodash to compare. But it always return incorrect result.

```
var editUser = function(userData, getOutFunction) {
    var status = CONSTANTS.NG;
    checkExistUser(userData._id).then(function(user) {
        if (user !== null) {
            var userGroup = JSON.stringify(user.group);
            user.group = user.group.map((groupId) => {
                return groupId.toString();
            });
            var removedGroups = _.difference(userGroup, userData.group);
            var addedGroups = _.difference(userData.group, userGroup);
            console.log('Removed Groups: ', removedGroups);
            console.log('Added Groups: ', addedGroups);
        } else {
            status = CONSTANTS.NG;
            logger.debug(DEBUG_CLASS_NAME, "Cannot find object");
            if (typeof(getOutFunction) !== 'undefined') {
                getOutFunction(status, null);
            } else {
                NO_CALLBACK();
            }
        }
    }).catch(function() {
        console.log('Promise is error');
    });

    var checkExistUser = function(userId) {
        return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
            UserDAO.findById(userId, function(err, user) {
                if (err) {
                    logger.debug(DEBUG_CLASS_NAME, {
                        name: err.name,
                        code: err.code,
                        message: err.message,
                        method: "checkExist"
                    });
                    resolve(null);
                } else {
                    resolve(user);
                }
            });
        });
    }
```

For example:When I try to input value for lodash difference function

```
var user.group = ["58b8da67d585113517fed34e","58b8da6ed585113517fed34f"];
var userData.group = [ '58b8da67d585113517fed34e' ];
```

I want lodash difference return below result:

Removed Groups:  `['58b8da6ed585113517fed34f']`

Added Groups:  `[]`

However, the function gave me the result like:

Removed Groups:  `[]`

Added Groups:  `[ '58b8da67d585113517fed34e' ]`

Can anyone help me in this case?
I will do appreciate it.

Answer (score 1):

I have had this issue as well, the result from mongodb is an ObjectId type so you can compare the someObjectId.toString() value with your array of strings, or you could use

```
someObjectId.equals(stringOrObjectIdValue)
```

However, if you want to keep using lodash functions you will either have to force both arrays to strings or to ObjectIds before passing them into the function.